# Show the details of what changed after PLAY RECAP in Ansible

Tags: ansible

For any given playbook with long list of tasks, is there a way to show what changed after the line of PLAY RECAP, **rather than scrolling up** and find each of them, pretty tedious:

```
PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
server1.abc.com        : ok=137  changed=34    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=65   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

For above example, how can I get a list of the changed items after the PLAY RECAP?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such functionality out of the box. I would consider looking through callback plugins [1] (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) and probably updating one of those to fit my needs, e.g. [this one] (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/selective.html). This is not a big deal to be honest - with a relatively little knowledge of python and ansible I have rewritten another plugin - slack - to do exactly what we need instead of its default behaviour for one day.

Answer (score 2):

actionable plugin is now deprecated. But you can use the default one and filter what you don't want. See config file or use environment variables:

```
export ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=false
export ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_OK_HOSTS=false
ansible-playbook ...
```

this will not display the skipped tasks and the already done tasks, leaving errors and changed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could still log the output matching `changed` in a file and then showing the file at the end and wrap it all in a run script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also display the changed/error status only, by using environment variable `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK` and setting it to `actionable` as in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069074/how-to-make-ansible-print-only-the-task-that-has-stdout). Your command would then be like:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable ansible-playbook ...
```

Cons: you lose the display of unchanged and skipped tasks.

Comment: NB: Deprecated option, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/76636326/1136400 instead.