# How to make Ansible print only the task that has stdout

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which contains multiple Tasks. I need Ansible to print only the Tasks which contains STDOUT /debug task

```
- hosts: "{{ v_host }}"
gather_facts: no
tasks:

- name: "Create /tmp in target in all VM's "
  file:
    path: /tmp
    state: directory
    owner: oracle
    group: oinstall
    mode: 0775

- copy:
    src: /xxx
    dest: /yyy
    owner: oracle
    group: oinstall
    force: yes
    mode: 0755

- name:  "Performing {{ patch_action }} of CPU patch on {{ v_host }} "
  shell: |
    cd /tmp
    sudo -u oracle ./patch.sh
  register: out
  
- debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

I execute the playbook without -v option to have a cleaner output. The output looks like below.

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars v_host=xyz.com.
    
TASK [Create /tmp in target in all VM's] ********************************************************************
ok: [ixyz.com]

TASK [copy] ********************************************************************
ok: [xyz.com]

TASK [Performing  of CPU patch on xyz.com] ***
changed: [xyz.com]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [xyz.com] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "Patch  123456     : applied on Tue Sep 29 10:11:58 GMT 2020", 
        "Patch description:  \"one-off\"", 
        "Patch  987654     : applied on Tue Sep 29 10:08:39 GMT 2020", 
        "Patch description:  \"One-off\"", 

    ]
}
```

Is there an option when i execute the playbook, it gives me the output only for the stdout/debug . The only output that i need is

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [xyz.com] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "Patch  123456     : applied on Tue Sep 29 10:11:58 GMT 2020", 
        "Patch description:  \"one-off\"", 
        "Patch  987654     : applied on Tue Sep 29 10:08:39 GMT 2020", 
        "Patch description:  \"One-off\"", 

    ]
}
```

Comment: what you can do is write this value in a file and read it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to select only changed tasks by using the callback *actionable*. See *"ansible-doc -t callback actionable"*

> *"Use this callback when you don't care about OK nor Skipped. This callback suppresses any non Failed or Changed status."*

For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /etc/passwd
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stat.mode
    - debug:
        msg: test message
      changed_when: actionable|default(false)|bool
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [stat] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stat.mode": "0644"
}

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test message"
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=3 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

The *actionable* callback will suppress the output. For example

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=3 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

You can enable the output of the selected tasks by controlling their *changed* status. For example

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "actionable=true"

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [debug] ****
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test message"
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=3 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

Q: **"*How can I execute my playbook using 'default' instead of 'actionable'?*"**

A: The command below gives the same results

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=false ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_OK_HOSTS=false  ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "actionable=true"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the desired output using the steps you suggested. However I checked the ansible doc and it says actionable is deprecated and it says we need to use "default".  How can i execute my playbook using "default" instead of "actionable".

Comment: You're welcome. It's deprecated. You're right. I still keep it using for simplicity. Configure the callback either in the configuration files or in the environment. I've added an example of how to configure the environment.

Comment: The "selective" callback looks promising. See `ansible-doc -t callback selective`. Unfortunately, the formatting is not working properly atm.